# How to set up multicore solr with Jetty

Tags: apache, solr, jetty, magento-1.4

I have set up solr3.6.2 in Ubuntu 14.04 and it's working fine. Now I want a multicore setup of this solr installation I have copied "core0", "core1" and solr.xml from

```
/opt/solr/example/multicore
```

to

```
/opt/solr/example/
```

and restarted jetty and solr. When I type  http://localhost:8983/solr/core0 , it gives 404 errror. How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

check the entries in the solr.xml file.
it should have the entries like

```
 <core name="core0" instanceDir="./"/>

 <core name="core1" instanceDir="./"/>
```

please refer the links below

http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.2/appendices/solr-multicore.html
                                                            http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.2/appendices/solr-multicore.html#creating-another-solr-core

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

Comment: I was doing little wrong. What we need to do is we need to create two folders for multicore "core0" and "core1" inside /solr/example/solr/ folder. Inside each core folder we need to add two folders namely conf and data.

Comment: Sorry dude, the correct answer is we need to create two core folders, inside them conf and data folders and the path to the data folders needs to be specified in solrconfig.xml in <dataDir> tag . Then we need to reindex it.  So in the data folder it will make index folders and it will create index files for each core inside the index folders separately.